# How to extract Lotus Notes database icon?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have tried to extract Lotus Notes database icon by using DXL Exporter but it is not success. Result file is corrupt and can not be opened by image viewer.

How can I extract Lotus Notes database icon by using java?

```
private String extractDatabaseIcon() {
    String tag = "";
    String idfile = "";
    String password = "";
    String dbfile = "";
    NotesThread.sinitThread();
    Session s = NotesFactory.createSessionWithFullAccess();
    s.createRegistration().switchToID(idfile, password);
    Database d = s.getDatabase("", dbfile);

    NoteCollection nc = d.createNoteCollection(false);
    nc.setSelectIcon(true);
    nc.buildCollection();
    String noteId = nc.getFirstNoteID();
    int counter = 0;
    while (noteId != null) {
        counter++;
        try {
            Document doc = d.getDocumentByID(noteId);
            DxlExporter dxl = s.createDxlExporter();
            String xml = dxl.exportDxl(doc);
            xml = xml.substring(xml.indexOf("<note "));
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document jdoc = Jsoup.parse(xml);
            Element ele = jdoc.select("rawitemdata").first();
            String raw = ele.text().trim();
            String temp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "\\";
            File file = new File(temp);
            file.mkdir();
            String filename = temp + UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "") + ".gif";
            byte[] buffer = decode(raw.getBytes());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.close();
            tag = filename;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("", e);
        }

        if (counter >= nc.getCount()) {
            noteId = null;
        } else {
            noteId = nc.getNextNoteID(noteId);
        }
   }
   return tag;
}

private byte[] decode(byte[] b) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
    InputStream b64is = MimeUtility.decode(bais, "base64");
    byte[] tmp = new byte[b.length];
    int n = b64is.read(tmp);
    byte[] res = new byte[n];
    System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, res, 0, n);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not even a bitmap, it is an icon. The format you can find here: 
http://www.daubnet.com/formats/ICO.html

I managed to do this, a long time ago, in LotusScript. My code was based on an earlier version of this page:
http://www2.tcl.tk/11202

For the icon itself, you only have to open one document:

```
NotesDocument doc = db.getDocumentByID("FFFF8010")
exporter = session.createDXLExporter
exporter.setConvertNotesBitmapsToGIF(false)
outputXML = exporter.export(doc)
```

and then parse the XML to find the rawitemdata from the IconBitmap item, as you did in your original code.

Comment: Use stream.Open( "dbicon.ico", "Binary") and stream.write(...)

Comment: How to get stream from Item? I only found item.getInputStream() but stream is always empty.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's very old code under a thick layer of dust... I modified the info above.

Comment: Last 512 bytes contains bitmap data. Image is 16-colors 32x32 bitmap. .See http://bryox.blogspot.com/2012/04/extract-lotus-notes-database-icon.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the format is.  As far as I know' it's a 16 color bitmap, but not in standard BMP file format.  And it's definitely not GIF format, but you can tell the DXLExporter to convert it.  The default is to leave it native, so you need to add this to your code before you export:

```
dxl.setConvertNotesBitmapsToGIF(true);
```

Comment: I have tried dxl.setConvertNotesBitmapsToGIF(true) but is is not success. Result file is still corrupt.