# xpages: retrieving database icon

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I want to rewrite the lotus notes workspace using xpages. 
So far i am successful but one feature is giving me quit a headache.

How can i access the database icon of a lotus notes application.

I tried to access: http://notespath.mydomain.com/$icon. That problem with that is that 
it is not using the login from the current session to access the database and 
retrieve the icon. Instead it tries to get it using the anonymous id. If the 
anonymous id has no access to the database i get a popup to login.

My question is: Is possible to do this with the user that is logged in to the xpage
or is there is a way to export the database icon into a notes document.

Comment: I'm not sure, but, would it be possible to store your icons in another, more open database, that you can access anonymously and reference programmatically?

Comment: sure would be fine. the problem is that we have to export all the existing icons into this application

Comment: I know it might be a pain, but could be a good time to modernize your application icons.

Answer (score 1):

Try following instructions here:

[How to extract Lotus Notes database icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834227/how-to-extract-lotus-notes-database-icon)

This should give you a method to get to the DXLExporter, and it looks like the icon is in the IconBitmap object. You're still going to get .ico files out though, which aren't ideal, but could be a good starting point for what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Also tried that one already. Exporting the design element with DXL is easy but the problem is that the dxl of the bitmap has to be converted to create a proper ico or bmp. I didnt find a converter for that.

Comment: Did you try this linked from that page? http://bryox.blogspot.com/2012/04/extract-lotus-notes-database-icon.html Seems to be a way to use Java to extract it to the file system.

Comment: Thanks that solved it for me. I am now able to write a java agent to export all icons.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that worked for you. If your issue is solved, please accept it as the answer for your question so it gets correctly marked in our system. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron Brake commented, XPages engine cannot access old Domino URL format for icon. Also see this: [Image URL when previewed in Notes and in Web Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363885/image-url-when-previewed-in-notes-and-in-web-browser/9369720#9369720)

In our applications we use dedicated 32x32 PNG image resource (img_DBIcon) which is used in XPages. Developers need to maintain this image resource.

Comment: Would be also a possibility but do you know a way to export the existing lotus notes database icon into this application. I couldnt find one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. I think the only thing you can do is open the icon editor and copy it to the clipboard, then paste that into a new image file (paint or photoshop). You'll lose most or all of the integrity of the image doing this, depending on its initial format. Edit: The Icon is not available in the XPages perspective, as it's not an XPage construct. Change your perspective to Domino Designer to see the Icon if it's not currently available.

Comment: manually exporting is not an option if you have hundred of nsfs on your server. thats why i need to export them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

What´s about if you change your URL to a database icon??

Don´t use http://notespath.mydomain.com/$icon

Try http://notespath.mydomain.com/DB.nsf/$icon

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Of course i tried server/db.nss/$Icon. That problem with that is that it tries to retrieve the icon with anonymous access and not with the id i am currently logged in